# How can I use 'transients' in 'magit' to enable case-insensitive search?

Tags: magit, search, case-folding, transients

I got it working a year ago, then my machine died. I've been unable to figure out the interface to transient.

When I view the levels (green and red, with numbers in them), I hit '-i' but see an error 'wrong type argument: (or eieio-object class), nil, obj'.

I'm not sure if that's a bug, or if I have to change the red 7 to a green 1 before I can enable that transient, and I haven't figured out how to do that either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a temporary (now fixed) upstream bug.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed that regression, see [#209](https://github.com/magit/transient/discussions/209).